# SQL SERVER: Lack of permissions for user to create copy of database with all privileges

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions, windows-server

#### First of all, here it is what I've got:

- two users: user and sa
- sa is database admin
- one main database with readonly permissions (db_datareader role) and executing some selected stored procedures (including database copying procedure) for user
- user has global dbcreator role
- SQL Server is located on a Windows Server machine with granted permissions for reading/writing files
- database copying stored procedure which when sa or user executes the procedure, it copies the db with all its content and granted permissions for user in original db. Afterwards sa has to map user to copied db and add him db_owner role.

#### What I already tried:

- to add execute as sa to procedure, but user can't IMPERSONATE sa (admin restriction)
- to add line to the procedure such as:
  `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::copyDB TO user`

Just been wondering, if there is any possibility to grant temporary permission to user or just grant him ownership for the copied database in any other way.

Comment: If the user creates the database, they *are* the owner. How are you "copying" it? By backing it up and restoring it, with a different name? If so, that would restore the database exactly it was, including permissions. If someone restored it who didn't initially have access to it, they still would not.

Comment: You are right, but is there any way to automate rights change without need of sa's interference on such backed up database?

Answer (score 0):

The secure way to handle this is to created a signed procedure that can do the database copy.  A user only has to have execute rights to run the procedure. The procedure will run using the context of the account used for signing, not as the user. Any change to the procedure requires re-signing. (Don't want somebody altering the code to do bad things.)

For example, I signed a procedure using an account with sysadmin access. It allowed users to execute a procedure using xp_cmdshell to execute COBOL without granting users sysadmin access. If a developer alters the code, it is no longer signed and executes using the normal context of the connection. This will cause it to fail if executing xp_cmdshell. DBA needs to verify the code and resign it before it will work again. This management overhead is the cost of security.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-signing-stored-procedures-with-a-certificate?view=sql-server-ver15

The signing is retained if restoring a backup to the same server. Restoring to a different server will require resigning. (The master database master key is normally different.)